# XAMPP phpMyAdmin access denied, cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have checked other answers where setting 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3307'` worked, but this does not work for me.

Running XAMPP on windows 7, I am getting the following:

MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

This worked perfectly until today, I did not touch anything, no updates.

I have to add, the database does run properly, I have a CRUD app I am testing, it adds items to the tables etc.

Another question would be, how to get phpMyAdmin to open in Chrome by default, as of now, it just open Opera, not sure why.

Ok, so after amending the configuration files, phpMyAdmin launches, but I have no more access to it.
I have set the password in the configuration file, tried to reset it in the shell, nothing works, here is a screenshot. The CLI error message is in the comment section.

[image: phpnightmares]

So, this was some journey, I have fixed this and many other issues.
Overall, I have to say, if you can use WAMPP over XAMPP, do so.

Nothing from the proposed answers helped, it had to be brute force. Resetting password in the shell, in the configuration file, nothing worked, except this:

I went to the shell and used the GRANT ALL PERMISSIONS TO etc.

Also, make sure to use the no cache meta tag with XAMPP, you will soon find out why if you don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't access XAMPP phpMyAdmin; it says: Error MySQL said: Documentation Cannot connect: invalid settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237044/i-cant-access-xampp-phpmyadmin-it-says-error-mysql-said-documentation-cannot)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237044/i-cant-access-xampp-phpmyadmin-it-says-error-mysql-said-documentation-cannot Check this question.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one thing, but now I cannot log in, I have changed the password in the inc.php file, but I still cannot get in.
Tried it in the shell with -u root password, but I get "access denied for root@localhost". I am new to this, tried to check other answers, but there is nothing conclusive.

Comment: localhost/phpmyadmin as address in google chrome

Comment: @Gunaseelan, I think you didn't embed that as a link, but I will google this.
The reason for this mess, I think, is precisely Opera, somehow the cookies got deleted,it's very odd.
Btw, I still cannot access the admin panel, Your link fixed the configuration but now I cannot get in, using roor as username and I have tried with and without password.
I get this access denied for user root and "using password(no)" in CLI.
Is there a way to just overrule everything?

Comment: Just enter the url in your browser. You will see a login page. Enter "root" as username and "password" as password. If it is not working, Enter "root" as username and don't enter password and hit enter button. localhost/phpmyadmin is not a link, it is the path to access phpmyadmin. Show the error screenshot that you got. Add the screenshot to the question.

Comment: Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.
user@USER-PC c:\xampp
#
user@USER-PC c:\xampp
# mysqladmin.exe -u root password secret
mysqladmin.exe: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

user@USER-PC c:\xampp
#
user@USER-PC c:\xampp
# mysladmin.exe -u root password secret
'mysladmin.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

This is the CLI error message I get

Comment: Ok screenshot is up. Btw, I meant to set Chrome as a default when I click admin in the xampp iframe, it opens up in Opera, no matter what. I thought you tried to put a link up with a how to page:-)